# Selenium Webdriver python: Element is not currently visible & same class name

Tags: python, selenium

I am using Selenium in python to click a button in a dialog. I try to click"OK", but it keeps getting errors

1. the buttons show "display:block" in CSS, cause "element is not visible" error
2. find_element_by_xpath, but the xpath of the element keeps changing
3. the class names are the same, how to choose the "OK" button?

Here are the code

```
<div<class="ui-dialog-buttonpane ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix">
 <div<class="ui-dialog-buttonset">
  <button type="button" class="large ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
   <span class="ui-button-text">Cancel</span>
  </button>
  <button type="button" class="orange large ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
   <span class="ui-button-text">OK</span>
  </button>
 </div>
</div>
```

Thank you:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the element is *invisible* in the DOM like css `{ display: None}`, `{opacity: 0}`... etc, , **selenium** will not be able to *SEE* it even given that you try to `wait` or `time.sleep`, instead you should use `execute_script` to run a JavaScript to trigger the desired event, something like this:

```
driver.execute_script('document.querySelector("span.ui-button-text").click();')
```

Answer (score 0):

You should wait for the element to be ready before trying to click on it. Use `waitForVisible` or similar to achieve that.
For example, something like this:

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
               lambda driver : driver.find_element_by_xpath(element_xpath)
            )
```

If the class remains the same, then you should select that class with `element_xpath`. The last thing you need to determine is what other attribute designates the button as ready. Then you can wait for the specific argument like:

```
def find(driver):
    e = driver.find_element_by_xpath(element_xpath)
        if (e.get_attribute(some_attribute)==some_value):
            return False
        return e

element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(find)
```

Comment: I try to use  'time.sleep(5)', but the element is still invisible and the xpath keeps changing every time I open the dialog. :(

Comment: Can you share the URL in question?

Answer (score 0):

Two different things can happen here.

• The selector is not explicitly returning the intended element

• Element load issue.

If both cases are true use explicit wait with a correct selector. In terms of selector I like using text bases search in such scenario. Notice I am using xpatth contains to make sure it eliminates any leading or tailing white spaces.

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH , "//span[contains(text(),'OK')]")))
```

API doc [here](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/waits.html#waits)