# How to find element on the page by keywords in list using Selenium?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to insert data into contact pages in some sites, but they have different html structure. So on the first page I have 3 fields (name, phone, message), on the second page I have 3 fields (first_name, phone, comment).

So I need using Python/Selenium find this fields (inputs/textareas) using *regexp*.

Main idea is build some lists with keywords (first_name, name, your_name, firstname etc) then try to find text field with this keywords (example: name="name").

Now i'm write this:

```
contact = ['telephone', 'cellphone', 'phone']

q = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(@name, 'phone')]")
```

So, the question is how to dynamically find all text fields and submit button on the contact pages of some sites by using lists of keyword?

Comment: Please share the HTML Code. It will help us to help you

Comment: @ShubhamJain HTML code are different. So i need to build dynamically script, which can find text fields on the contact pages.

Comment: It can be done quite easily but from your description it seems like you are trying to spam other websites... :-/

Comment: @Anzel, nope :)
It's just 10 websites(it change every day), which i need to contact.

Comment: OK, in that case I can help :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in comment, it can be done quite easily by chaining a xpath query with "or", one way to do it:

```
# I use lxml to demo the xpath, which should be the same as in selenium
In [7]: from lxml import html

# just a sample
In [8]: s = """<div id="contact-area"> 
   ...:            <form method="post" action="contactengine.php">
   ...:                <label for="Name">Name:</label>
   ...:                <input type="text" name="Name" id="Name" />
   ...:                <label for="City">City:</label>
   ...:                <input type="text" name="City" id="City" />  
   ...:                <label for="Email">Email:</label>
   ...:                <input type="text" name="Email" id="Email" />
   ...:                <label for="Message">Message:</label><br />
   ...:                <textarea name="Message" rows="20" cols="20" id="Message"></textarea>
   ...:                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="submit-button" />
   ...:            </form>
   ...:        <div style="clear: both;"></div>
   ...:    </div>"""

In [9]: tree = html.fromstring(s)

In [10]: contact = ["Name", "Phone", "Message", "Comment"] 

# construct the query with "or" chaining with all keywords 
In [11]: query = " or ".join("contains(@name, '%s')" % field for field in contact)

In [12]: query
Out[12]: "contains(@name, 'Name') or contains(@name, 'Phone') or contains(@name, 'Message') or contains(@name, 'Comment')"
```

Results:

```
In [13]: tree.xpath("//*[%s]" % query)
Out[13]: 
[<InputElement 10e34c8e8 name='Name' type='text'>,
 <TextareaElement 10e34c9f0 name='Message'>]
```

Hope this helps.

**Edit**:

Since your elements are somehow invisible by the time the page loads (either by css or JavaScript), please refer to my another answer in this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29932091/selenium-webdriver-python-element-is-not-currently-visible-same-class-name/29933749#29933749) to execute JavaScript to "enable" those elements' visibilities.

I will not give detailed explanation here as this should really belong to another question.

Comment: Looks good. But i'm getting error:

selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
Stacktrace


I use this code:

`from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

driver.get("http://strikeball2.com.ua/contacts")

driver.maximize_window()

contact = ['telephone', 'cellphone', 'phone', 'telefon']

query = " or ".join("contains(@name, '%s')" % field for field in contact)

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[%s]" % query).click()`

What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: @AndreyIlyin, the reason above is because selenium can only "SEE" the visible elements, if the page somehow hides them -- either by css or generated by JS and thus by the time you "find_elements_by_xpath" it won't find it.

Comment: @AndreyIlyin I have edited the answer to provide a link which gives you an idea how to proceed from there. By if my current answer does help resolve your question, please accept my answer by clicking the "tick" at top left near my answer. Your comment above should really be another question -- but like I said, it's also answered and given you a direction where to go

Comment: @Anzel would this be possible if we didn't know what attribute we should be looking at? In this case we are targeting `name` by saying `@name`. What if we didn't know that we should be looking for the context in `name`, would it be possible to check all the fields/attributes/tags?

Comment: @AsheKetchum, you can look up for all attributes with a wildcard '.', that is, `.xpath("//*[contains(., 'keyword')]")`